# Powershell Excel Conditional copy loop running slow

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a powershell script that creates a new worksheet for each unique item in column A, and then copies the relevant rows for each unique item to the respective worksheets. It is working correctly, it is simply very slow and I am wondering if there is an easy way to speed it up. Here is the script:

```
$arrExcelValues = @()
$executingScriptDirectory = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent
$path1 = Join-Path $executingScriptDirectory "my_workbook.xls"
$Excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
$Excel.Visible = $False
$Workbook1 = $Excel.Workbooks.open($path1)
$Worksheet1 = $Workbook1.WorkSheets.item(2) 

$rowCount = $worksheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
$colCount = $worksheet1.UsedRange.Columns.Count
$i = 2
Do {
    $arrExcelValues += $Worksheet1.Cells.Item($i, 1).Value()
    $i++
}
While ($Worksheet1.Cells.Item($i,1).Value() -ne $null)
foreach ($objItem in $arrExcelValues) {
    write-host $objItem 
}
$arrExcelValues = $arrExcelValues | select -uniq

$x=0
While ($x -ne $arrExcelValues.length) {
$Workbook1.Worksheets.add([System.Reflection.Missing]::Value,$Workbook1.Worksheets.Item($Workbook1.Worksheets.count))
$sheet_new = $Workbook1.worksheets.Item($Workbook1.Worksheets.count)
$sheet_new.name = $arrExcelValues[$x]
$SaveSheet = $Workbook1.WorkSheets.item($arrExcelValues[$x])

# Copy header row...
1..($ColCount) | % {$SaveSheet.Cells.Item(1,$_) = $Worksheet1.Cells.Item(1,$_)}

# Find rows to copy...
$TestName = $arrExcelValues[$x]
$SaveRow = 2
2..($rowCount) | % {
    If (($Worksheet1.Cells.Item($_,1).Text).ToUpper() -match $TestName) {
        $row = $_
        1..($ColCount) | % {$SaveSheet.Cells.Item($SaveRow,$_) = $Worksheet1.Cells.Item($Row,$_).Text}
        $SaveRow ++}
}
$x++
}

$workbook1.Save()
$workbook1.close($true)
$Excel.Quit()
Remove-Variable -Name excel 
Remove-Variable -Name Worksheet1 
Remove-Variable -Name Workbook1 
Remove-Variable -Name path1
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$Excel.Visible = $Falsefalse` try to use `$Excel.ScreenUpdating = $false`

Perhaps that will make a difference ?